# Compare of dictionaries in list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare

How can I find duplicated dictionaries in list of dictionaries. I know how to compare two dictionaries, but how to this in loop?

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> allLists = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
 foreach (Dictionary<string, string> allList in allLists)
            {
                
            }
```

This is how you do it when comparing two dictionaries and I want to be able to do similar to list of dictionaries:

```
public static void CompareDict()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Dictionary<string, object> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dic1.Add("Key1", new { Name = "abc", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            dic1.Add("Key2", new { Name = "DEF", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            dic1.Add("Key3", new { Name = "GHI", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            dic1.Add("Key4", new { Name = "JKL", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });

            dic2.Add("Key1", new { Name = "abc", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            dic2.Add("Key2", new { Name = "DEF", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            dic2.Add("Key3", new { Name = "GHI", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            dic2.Add("Key4", new { Name = "JKL", Number = "123", Address = "def", Loc = "xyz" });
            bool result = dic1.SequenceEqual(dic2);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Comment: Do you just want to check _whether_ there are duplicated dictionaries, or do you want to find which dictionaries are duplicated?

Comment: I want to check whether there duplicated dictionaries, doesn't care which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably creating a generic dictionary equality comparer:

```
public class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> :
    IEqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public bool Equals(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> x, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d)
    {
        var hash = default(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>).GetHashCode();
        
        foreach (var kp in d)
            hash ^= kp.GetHashCode();
            
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And now, you can group dictionaries to check for duplicates:

```
var hasDups = allLists.GroupBy(d => d, new DictionaryComparer<string, string>())
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 ={ "employee" : [{"name": "employee1", "id":1234},
        {"name": "employee2" ,"id":2345},
        {"name": "employee3", "id":3456},
        {"name": "employee4" ,"id":4567}]
}
dict2 ={ "employee" : [{"name": "employee4" ,"id":4567},
        {"name": "employee2" ,"id":2345},
        {"name": "employee3", "id":3456},
        {"name": "employee1" ,"id":1234}]
}
print("equal",dict1==dict2)
print (dict1,dict2)
print (dict1.keys())
print (dict2.keys())
print("*****",dict1.items())

for i,j in dict1.items():
    len1 = len(j)
    for k,l in dict2.items():
       len2 = len(l)
       if i == k:
           print ("keys are same")
           if len1==len2:
               for m in range(len1):
                   print("OOO",dict1[i][m].items())
                   for a,b in dict1[i][m].items():
                       for c,d in dict2[k][m].items():
                           if a == c and b==d:
                               print("same")
                      
           else :
               pass
       else:
           print ("keys are different")
           break
In this code checking for similar dictionaries having list of dictionaries.
```